# Total number of strings constructed by a set of $N$ characters.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_N\}$ be a set of $N$ characters. What is the total number of strings that could be constructed using elements of the above set, granted that strings may be of length at least $1$ and each character is used only once?

For instance, for $N=2$, i.e., $S=\{s_1,s_2\}$, the number of all possible strings is equal to $4$. That is, these strings are the following: $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_1s_2$, and $s_2s_1$. If I am not mistaken, for $N=3$, this number is equal to $15$.

How could I compute this number analytically for an arbitrary choice of $N$? I am a bit stuck on this, so thank you very much for any help in advance!

Comment: It smells like something along the lines of $\binom{N}{1} + 2\binom{N}{2}+6\binom{N}{3}+\cdots+N!\binom{N}{N}$, I think.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that is fits, but also seems to be right. I think it is! Thanks again!

Comment: no problem. :) What I would like to know, though, is if the expression above has a more simple closed form.

Comment: Yes, that's something I would like to know too! Feel free to post it as an answer below if you come up with it!

Comment: @HowDoIMath Won't that work only when every character in S in unique?

Comment: @JLee yes, you're right. I used that as an assumption without thinking about it.

Comment: @JLee, indeed, this is an assumption I stated above. Each character may be used only once.

Comment: For example, if S is {A,B,B}, then duplicates are created, even though each character in the set is used only once in each created string.

Comment: @JLee $S$ is a set, as I said above.

Comment: Am I missing something? Is {A,B,B} not a set of 3 characters?

Comment: @JLee, yes, a set is a collection of **distinct** objects. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29

Comment: How is it possible to construct a string of length three if you only have two characters, and each character can only be used once?

Comment: @AndrewWoods, you cannot. The maximum length of the string is equal to the cardinality of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sloane has the sequence: https://oeis.org/A007526

He provides this amazing looking closed form for the general expression:

$\lfloor e\cdot N!-1\rfloor$

I haven't checked it, and have no idea why it is true, but I believe I saw something similar for derangements at some point.

Comment: Although I cannot really "read" the content of your link, the closed-form expression really looks amazing! I will check this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Using the expression $\operatorname{T}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k!{n \choose k}$ provided by HowDoIMath above, we can rewrite it as a recursive function:
\begin{split}
\operatorname{T}(n+1) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k!{n+1 \choose k} = \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)!{n+1 \choose k+1} =
\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)!\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n+1-k-1)!} \\
&= (n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n k!\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = (n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n \choose k} = \\
&= (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n k!{n \choose k} +(n+1) = (n+1)\operatorname{T}(n) + (n+1).
\end{split}
The recurrence equation $\operatorname{T}(n)=n \operatorname{T}(n-1)+n$, with $\operatorname{T}(1)=1$, has solution
$$
\operatorname{T}(n)=e\cdot n\cdot\Gamma(n,1),
$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the [upper incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). I found this solution by messing around in Mathematica, but once you have it, it is easy enough to prove that is the solution, by showing that it satisfies the recurrence relation, using integration by parts, and testing the initial value.

Now
\begin{split}
\Gamma(n,1) &= \int_1^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt -\int_0^1 t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt \\
&= \Gamma(n,0)-\int_0^1 t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt = (n-1)!-\int_0^1 t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt,
\end{split}
using that $\Gamma(n,0)$ is the usual gamma function $\Gamma(n)$. So we arrive at
$$
\operatorname{T}(N)=e\cdot N!-e\cdot N\int_0^1 t^{N-1}e^{-t}dt.
$$
We still have to prove that this is equal to $\lfloor e\cdot N!-1 \rfloor$, as mentioned again by HowDoIMath, but at least it's part of the way!

Answer (score 4):

I'll show that HowDoIMath's answer $T(n)$ is equivalent to $\lfloor e\cdot n!-1\rfloor$.

Rewrite $T(n)$ as $n!\binom{n}0+(n-1)!\binom{n}1+(n-2)!\binom{n}2+\ldots+(n-(n-1))!\binom{n}{n-1}$.

Divide by $n!$ to get: $$T(n)=n!(\tbinom{n}0+\tfrac1n\tbinom{n}1+\tfrac1{n(n-1)}\tbinom{n}2+\ldots+\tfrac1{n(n-1)\ldots2}\tbinom{n}{n-1})$$
$$\therefore\ T(n)=n!(1+1+\tfrac1{2!}+\tfrac1{3!}+\ldots+\tfrac1{(n-1)!})$$

Thus $T(n)=n!(e-\tfrac1{n!}-f(n))$ where $f(n)=\tfrac1{(n+1)!}+\tfrac1{(n+2)!}+\tfrac1{(n+3)!}+\ldots$

Expanding, $T(n)=e\cdot n!-1-n!f(n)$.

We already know that this is an integer, so all that remains is to show that $n!f(n)<1$.

$$n!f(n)=\tfrac1{n+1}+\tfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)}+\tfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\ldots$$

But $$e-2=\tfrac12+\tfrac1{2\cdot3}+\tfrac1{2\cdot3\cdot4}+\ldots<1$$

By the comparison test, for $n>1$ each term of $n!f(n)$ is smaller than the corresponding term in $e-2$. Therefore the series converges, and is less than $1$.