# How to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n k! \cdot \binom{n}{k}=\lfloor e \cdot n! - 1 \rfloor$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The integer sequence [A007526](https://oeis.org/A007526) is a sequence with many equivalent formulations. I have noticed the following expression, which seems to be correct. However, I am not sure how to prove it.

**Prove that** $$\sum_{k=1}^n k! \cdot \binom{n}{k}=\lfloor e \cdot n! - 1 \rfloor$$

[image]

How is the constant $e$ derived?

**Another question:**
If I define $s = \lfloor e \cdot n! - 1 \rfloor$, can I solve for $n = f(s)$?

I try this:
We can let $e\cdot n！-1=s+\alpha $ where $0\le \alpha<1$. Then $n!=\frac{s+\alpha +1}{e}$. But I do not know if there is a symbolic representation for the **inverse operation** of **factorial** (n!).

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1194024/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20k!%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%24)

Comment: The constant $e$ seems to appear because on the left you have kind of a truncation of $e$. Recall that $e$ is defined as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$.

Comment: Note that $
\sum_{k = 1}^n {k!\frac{{n!}}{{k!(n - k)!}}}  = n!\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{k!}}} 
$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. My additional question is whether there is a possibility to solve for the inverse of that equation.

Comment: For your second question see [Inverse of a factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078997/42969)

Comment: Please, don't use images unless really necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @Gary comment
$$A_n=\sum_{k = 1}^n {k!\frac{{n!}}{{k!(n - k)!}}}  = n!\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{k!}}}=e \,n\, \Gamma (n,1)$$
Asymptotically
$$A_n \sim  \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{1-n} n^{n-\frac{1}{2}} (12
   n+1)-\frac{n+1}{n}$$ is a very decent approximation (relative error smaller than $0.01$% if $n>5$).

Solving for $n$ the equation
$$\log\left(\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{1-n} n^{n-\frac{1}{2}} (12
   n+1)-\frac{n+1}{n} \right)=\log(s)$$ will not make any problem using Newton method.

Let me try for $s=123456789$ with the ridiculous $n_0=1$. Newton iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n_k \\
 0 & 1.00000 \\
 1 & 7.31520 \\
 2 & 11.4305 \\
 3 & 11.0552 \\
 4 & 11.0528 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can generate the first estimate of Newton method for the zero of function
$$f(n)=\log(e \,n\, \Gamma (n,1))-\log(s)$$ starting with $n_0=1$. It is given by
$$n_1=1+\frac{\log (s)}{1-e \,\text{Ei}(-1)}$$ where appears  the the exponential integral function.

Converted to rational numbers, this is
$$n_1=1+\frac{109}{174}\,\log(s)$$

For the worked example, this gives $n_1=12.6713$.

Using $s=10^k$ some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & n_1 & n_2 & \text{solution}\\
 1 & 2.44241 & 2.70237 &  2.70019 \\
 2 & 3.88482 & 4.29521 &  4.28579 \\
 3 & 5.32723 & 5.64096 &  5.63655 \\
 4 & 6.76963 & 6.84323 &  6.84305 \\
 5 & 8.21204 & 7.95886 &  7.95713 \\
 6 & 9.65445 & 9.01519 &  9.00608 \\
 7 & 11.0969 & 10.0274 &  10.0058 \\
 8 & 12.5393 & 11.0051 &  10.9666 \\
 9 & 13.9817 & 11.9544 &  11.8953 \\
 10 & 15.4241 & 12.8802 &  12.7972 \\
 11 & 16.8665 & 13.7856 &  13.676 \\
 12 & 18.3089 & 14.6734 &  14.5347 \\
 13 & 19.7513 & 15.5455 &  15.3757 \\
 14 & 21.1937 & 16.4038 &  16.2009 \\
 15 & 22.6361 & 17.2495 &  17.0118 \\
 16 & 24.0785 & 18.0838 &  17.8098 \\
 17 & 25.5209 & 18.9078 &  18.5960 \\
 18 & 26.9634 & 19.7221 &  19.3714 \\
 19 & 28.4058 & 20.5276 &  20.1367 \\
 20 & 29.8482 & 21.3249 &  20.8929 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Thanking @Gary who, in comments, pushed me, we have
$$ \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{1-n} n^{n-\frac{1}{2}} (12
   n+1)-\frac{n+1}{n}=s$$ Neglecting the $1$ gives
$$\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{1-n} n^{n+\frac 12}=s+1\implies e^{-(n+\frac 12)}\,n^{n+\frac 12}=\frac{(s+1)\,e^{\frac 32}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ that what also approximate as
$$ e^{-(n+\frac 12)}\,\left(n+\frac 12\right)^{n+\frac 12}=\frac{(s+1)\,e^{\frac 32}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
So
$$n+\frac 12=\frac{\log (k)}{W\left(\frac{\log (k)}{e}\right)}\qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac{(s+1)\,e^{\frac 32}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

For $s=123456789$, this gives $n=12.0557$.

For $s=10^{20}$, it gives $n=21.7035$.

One or two iterations of Newton method would give the solution

Comment: Try getting an approximate inverse using the Lambert W-function.

Comment: @Gary. I tried and ... failed. It is so close to Lambert !

Comment: @Gary. I just found it. I shall edit. Thanks for pushing me !

Comment: Let me push you once more. You missed the fact that $$
\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{n + 1/2}  = n^{n + 1/2} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}}} \right)^{n + 1/2}  \sim n^{n + 1/2} {\rm e}^{1/2} .
$$ Therefore, you may replace $\mathrm{e}^{3/2}$ by $\mathrm{e}^2$ in the definition of $k$. Give it a try!